# Get Future Years based on a field on a Table for an Employee

Tags: oracle, date

I have a requirement to get the future years based on a field available for employee on the Employee table and the benefits date ,Below are the two tables and the expected output is shown below for the two employess XYZ and ABC.
Tabular Data for Employee

[image]

Employee benefit Date table

[image]

Expected Output 
[image]

Case 1 --Say an Employee XYZ has value of 5 and the query is run for 03/31/2020 ,then the query would need to return as below
Input - 03/31/2020
Expected Output in rows
2020 
2021 
2022 
2023 
2024 
2025+

Case 2 
Say an Employee ABC has value of 10 and the query is run for 03/31/2020 ,then the query would need to return as below
Input - 03/31/2020
Expected Output in rows--
2020 
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
2026
2027
2028
2029
2030+

Requesting for logic to derive the years based on employee table second column and all the years above it should be shown as (year)+.
I have tried using case statements for getting years ,but would like to get someassiatcne to this dynamically based on the value field.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't understand, and you haven't really explained, the business logic, and meaning of 'benifit_date', 'years', and 'maturity'.  I could easily be wrong but I'm getting the gnawing suspicion that you are trying to store a value that actually changes daily - something like storing 'empoyee_age', when what should be stored is 'employee_date_of_birth', with 'age' always calculated at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option; See comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  emp (employee, years) as
  4    (select 'XYZ',  5 from dual union all
  5     select 'ABC', 10 from dual
  6    ),
  7  benefit (employee, bdate) as
  8    (select 'XYZ', 2021 + level - 1
  9     from dual
 10     connect by level <= 7
 11     union all
 12     select 'ABC', 2021 + level - 1
 13     from dual
 14     connect by level <= 13
 15    )
 16  select
 17    b.employee,
 18    case when b.bdate = x.bdate + e.years then to_char(b.bdate - 1) || '+'
 19         else to_char(b.bdate)
 20    end bdate
 21  from benefit b join emp e on e.employee = b.employee
 22  join (-- find MIN(bdate) per employee
 23        select b1.employee,
 24               min(b1.bdate) bdate
 25        from benefit b1
 26        group by b1.employee
 27       ) x on x.employee = b.employee
 28  and b.bdate <= (-- limit number of rows displayed
 29                  select min(b1.bdate) + e.years
 30                  from benefit b1
 31                  where b1.employee = b.employee
 32                 )
 33  order by b.employee desc, b.bdate;

EMP BDATE
--- -----------------------------------------
XYZ 2021
XYZ 2022
XYZ 2023
XYZ 2024
XYZ 2025
XYZ 2025+
ABC 2021
ABC 2022
ABC 2023
ABC 2024
ABC 2025
ABC 2026
ABC 2027
ABC 2028
ABC 2029
ABC 2030
ABC 2030+

17 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Desired output you posted is kind of inconsistent; for `XYZ`, it says `2026+` which doesn't match `ABC`'s `2030+` (should be `2031+`) (or, `XYZ` should be `2025+` if `ABC` is correct). Anyway, that's easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the kind assistance,my expected output was wrongly put there for XYZ,sorry for that.Thanks Again.